# How to show items from multiple ArrayList in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have multiple arraylist in my Android studio project (Java) like :

```
firstArray = [1,2,3]
secondtArray = [A,B,C]
thirdArrayt = [X,Y,Z]
```

Now I want to populate my recyclerview with the items from these arraylist.Each time i want to show  the spicific index from all the lists.
For example, in my first view i want to show firstArray[0],secondArray[0] and thirdArray[0] in my viewholder.
How do I get that?

Comment: Are the three `ArrayList` of the same size?

Comment: Yes.All of them are same sized.